# Check if an especific equation is a consequence of others (noncommutative scenario)

Tags: group-theory, systems-of-equations, group-presentation

Let $\Sigma = \{a, b, c, ..., x, y, w\}$ be a set of formal variables, $\Sigma^{-1} = \{a^{-1}, b^{-1}, ..., w^{-1}\}$ be the inverses of those variables, and $B = \{ e_1, e_2, ..., e_n \}$ be a set of equations involving products of those variables and their inverses in the left hand side and one in the right side.

So, each $e_i$ is of the form $\Pi_{i=1}^m \bar{x}_i = 1$ with $\bar{x}_i \in \Sigma \cup \Sigma^{-1}$.

Also, assume that those variables do not commute.

For instance, we could have $e_1$ as $axk^{-1} = 1$, $e_2$ as $k^{-1}xak = 1$, $e_3$ as $b^2xyx = 1$, etc.

Is there a general algorithm to decide if a new equation $e_{n+1}$ with the same format is a consequence of those in $B$?

---

PS: In fact, this is the problem of deciding if a given relation $e_{n+1}$ of a finitely presented group $\langle \Sigma |  B\cup \{e_{n+1}\} \rangle$ can be derived from the relations in $B$...

Comment: The property that you describe in your PS is equivalent to the word problem in finitely presented groups, which was proved to be undecidable in the 1950s. So there is no such algorithm.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, now that you said that, I've searched for that and it is actually simple to reduce one problem to the other... Anyway, don't you want to write that as an answer so that I can mark this question as solved?